# Android SQLite SELECT SUM filter by specific column

Tags: android, sqlite

I need help with summing the values in one of the columns in my database. I need sum values by a specific parameter, for example a foreign key.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + tool.CAMP_PRICE + ") FROM " + tool.TABLE_DATE + " WHERE " + tool.ID_PAC_FOREIGN);
```

- `CAMP_PRICE` is the camp that I want sum
- `TABLE_DATE` is the table
- `ID_PAC_FOREIGN` is the foreign key

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "by"?

Comment: What I need is for me to sum values from a field based on another field, such as a foreign key, for example.

Comment: What do you mean with "based on"? Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer may be something like that:

```
String foreignKey = "your_foreign_key";
String column = tool.ID_PAC_FOREIGN;

String whereCondition = String.format("%s = %s", column, foreignKey);

String sql = String.format("" +
        "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN %s IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE %s) " +
        "FROM %s " +
        "WHERE %s"
        // SELECT
        tool.CAMP_PRICE, tool.CAMP_PRICE,
        // FROM
        tool.TABLE_DATE,
        // WHERE
        whereCondition
);

db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: Thanks!,  But it gives me a syntax error, I'll keep trying to fix it, although with this at least I have an idea of how to do it.